# django admin: company branches must manage only their records across many models

Tags: python, django, django-admin, personalization

One company with many branches across the world using the same app. Each branch's supervisor, signing into the same /admin, should see and be able to manage only their records across many models (blog, galleries, subscribed users, clients list, etc.).

How to solve it best within django? I need a flexible and reliable solution, not hacks. Never came across this task, so really have no idea how to do it for the moment.

Tx

Comment: Does your model have any columns to support "only their records"?  Could you show your model?  Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: obviously it will have such a column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice tutorial [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-django-admin/) on Django Admin. It includes customizing the Admin to add row-level permissions (which, as i understand it, is what you want).

Comment: tx, that's it!

"Of course, nothing currently prevents a determined user from accessing an edit page for an unauthorized document by knowing its ID. Truly secure row-level permissions require more method overriding. Because admin users are generally trusted to some degree anyway, sometimes basic permissions are enough to provide a streamlined workflow. "

if you had any ready made solution for that one, i'd be thankful, if not i'll try it myself later.